# Не работает прелодер для галереи

Tags: javascript, css

Есть галерея, скринт с настройками галереи и стили для прелодера. Но прелодер не срабатывает и все изображения с галереей грузятся за раз, выглядит ужасно.

Где я ошибся?

```
<script type="text/javascript">
jQuery(window).load(function(){
    jQuery("#slider").nivoSlider({
        effect:"random",
        slices:15,
        boxCols:8,
        boxRows:4,
        animSpeed:500,
        pauseTime:3000,
        startSlide:0,
        directionNav:true,
        directionNavHide:true,
        controlNav:true,
        controlNavThumbs:false,
        controlNavThumbsFromRel:true,
        keyboardNav:false,
        pauseOnHover:false,
        manualAdvance:false
    });
});
</script>
<style>
#slider .nivoSlider (
position: relative;
/ / Смотрим “style-pack” ниже изображения
background: url (/i/loader.gif) no-repeat 50% 50%;
)
#slider .nivoSlider img (
position: absolute;
top: 0px;
left: 0px;
display: none;
)
</style>
<div id="slider" class="nivoSlider" style="position: relative; height: 376px; background-image: url(http://tmhomes.pirogov.ru/upload/iblock/22d/5908f1461263321e9e78ac71712423f5.png); background-attachment: initial; background-origin: initial; background-clip: initial; background-color: initial; background-position: initial initial; background-repeat: no-repeat no-repeat; ">
<img src="/upload/iblock/b1b/e445e3ffe18bcc4cb1856691a6134f4d.jpg" alt="" style="display: none; ">
<img src="/upload/iblock/de8/ab5b4651c1e7984c27f214fb8ade194b.jpg" alt="" style="display: none; ">
<img src="/upload/iblock/e69/a9ec765c481e02757936c9bcd0779b98.jpg" alt="" style="display: none; ">
<img src="/upload/iblock/22d/5908f1461263321e9e78ac71712423f5.png" alt="" style="display: none; ">
<img src="/upload/iblock/2a4/830a2252e7257d41a1ddf991e8303811.jpg" alt="" style="display: none; ">
<div class="nivo-caption" style="display: none; opacity: 0.8; "><p></p></div><div class="nivo-directionNav" style="display: none; "><a class="nivo-prevNav">Prev</a><a class="nivo-nextNav">Next</a></div><div class="nivo-controlNav"><a class="nivo-control" rel="0">1</a><a class="nivo-control" rel="1">2</a><a class="nivo-control" rel="2">3</a><a class="nivo-control" rel="3">4</a><a class="nivo-control active" rel="4">5</a></div><div class="nivo-box" style="left: 0px; top: 0px; background-image: url(http://tmhomes.pirogov.ru/upload/iblock/2a4/830a2252e7257d41a1ddf991e8303811.jpg); background-attachment: initial; background-origin: initial; background-clip: initial; background-color: initial; overflow-x: hidden; overflow-y: hidden; opacity: 0.21147016581541989; width: 131px; height: 94px; background-position: 0px 0px; background-repeat: no-repeat no-repeat; "></div><div class="nivo-box" style="left: 131px; top: 0px; background-image: url(http://tmhomes.pirogov.ru/upload/iblock/2a4/830a2252e7257d41a1ddf991e8303811.jpg); background-attachment: initial; background-origin: initial; background-clip: initial; background-color: initial; overflow-x: hidden; overflow-y: hidden; opacity: 0.00481267299994248; width: 131px; height: 94px; background-position: -131px 0px; background-repeat: no-repeat no-repeat; "></div><div class="nivo-box" style="opacity: 0; left: 262px; top: 0px; width: 131px; height: 94px; background-image: url(http://tmhomes.pirogov.ru/upload/iblock/2a4/830a2252e7257d41a1ddf991e8303811.jpg); background-attachment: initial; background-origin: initial; background-clip: initial; background-color: initial; background-position: -262px 0px; background-repeat: no-repeat no-repeat; "></div><div class="nivo-box" style="opacity: 0; left: 393px; top: 0px; width: 131px; height: 94px; background-image: url(http://tmhomes.pirogov.ru/upload/iblock/2a4/830a2252e7257d41a1ddf991e8303811.jpg); background-attachment: initial; background-origin: initial; background-clip: initial; background-color: initial; background-position: -393px 0px; background-repeat: no-repeat no-repeat; "></div></div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если вы действительно хотите использовать `Nivo Slider`, то вы можете просто использовать *любой работающий пример* с прелоадером с их сайта (http://nivo.dev7studios.com) и настроить его по своему усмотрению.